# What am I doing wrong in my document uploader code?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim objCars As Objects.Cars = CType(txtSearchCarsName.Text, Objects.Cars)
        If Not objCars Is Nothing Then

            Dim frmDocumentUploader As New CarsDocumentUploader
            frmDocumentUploader.CarsID = objCars.CarsID
            frmDocumentUploader.Cars = objCars 
            frmDocumentUploader.ShowDialog()

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Car.", "Car Search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End If
```

I am trying to open a document uploader based on a car ID

Comment: Try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. We can't read your mind. If you hit that code then there are only three possible outcomes (dialogue, message box or exception) and you haven't told us which occurs. If none of the three then that code is not being hit. Either way, YOU need to debug your code properly and provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: The error is value of type String cannot be converted to Data.Objects.Cars

Comment: It doesn't let me execute the program

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do using that first line of code? I'm guessing that you want to search for a car using the TextBox value as a parameter for the search and then upload it. You can't just convert a string to a car object. What you need to do is search the list/array/database for the object and pass THAT to objCars.

Comment: thanks, fix the error